# How to use Ionic components inside Cordova project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid, phonegap

Can we use ionic components like ion-buttons, ion-card, ion-refresher, etc inside cordova project? If yes then how??

I want to use pull-to-refresh functionality in cordova project using ion-refresher. Is it really possible?

Comment: Ionic projects are Cordova projects. But you can't just use some Ionic parts, you need the whole Ionic library

Answer (score 0):

Cordova doesn't use components like ionic, you have to build them on your own using HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Like jcesmobile says, Ionic es based in cordova so the answer is yes.
Remember that Ionic depends on AngularJS (http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/)

You just need to import ionic components to your own components.

In case of pull-to-refresh yo need to implement like this https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/.

I hope it'll help you